# Does javaw.exe process in windows 64 consuming more memory?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jvm, 64-bit

I switched from Windows 7 (32 bit) to Windows 7 (64 bit) because i added 4 Gb RAM to my 2 GB.
And now when I'm running `Eclipse Juno EE`. In Windows Task Manager I see that process `javaw.exe` is eating ~380 Mb RAM, I didn't saw this before, when I was using 32-bit OS. 
I didn't even try to lunch any projects.
I wrote this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    System.out.println(runtime.maxMemory());
}
```

It shows that for my `JVM is allocated 1 338 507 264 bytes`.

It means that when I will run projects, this process may consume up to 1.3 Gb Ram ?!

Will I have any problems with this in future ?

Comment: On a 6GB machine, 380MB is nothing to worry about.  There's no point in leaving RAM unused, after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 64-bit version will use the `-server` JVM and it has a higher default maximum heap size.  The Windows 32-bit version uses the `-client` JVM by default and it uses less resources by default as it designed to run on smaller machines, it tends to be slower for long running programs as a result (the client JVM has faster loads for short running programs like applets)

If you set the maximum heap size, they should use about the same amount of memory if you have a recent version of Java 6, or Java 7.

Comment: Not directly related to the op's issue - I thought I had read somewhere that the same program uses more memory with a 64 bit JVM (I think it was in the order of 50% or so)...

Comment: Java 5 and early Java 6 didn't use CompressedOops (32-bit references) and resulted in about 50% increase in memory consumption.  It is for this reason that 32 GB is not a good heap size (as you lose Compressed Oops) and you need to go up to 48 GB to get more usable memory.  There is still an increase but I suspect it's closer to 10% and not something you are likely to notice.

Comment: And how can I set the heap size?

Comment: I set it using `-mx1000m` or `-mx1g`  Most people use the non-standard but popular `-Xmx1000m` and `-Xmx1g` which do the same thing.  Note: this sets the maximum heap size which is the main, but not the only user of memory.  You can expect a couple of 100 MB of shared libraries to be added and thread stack spaces to be created as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you explain what is the difference between server JVM and client JVM except that server JVM consuming more memory?

Comment: The server JVM was design for server based applications. It spends more time compiling the code which impacts load times but has more efficient running over time.  The client version was designed for small client apps. e.g. Applets and Swing GUIs where load time was more important.  To confuse the issue these two have been made more a like over time so that the main difference is that the default parameters are not the same. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: The Windows 32-bit version was considered to be for clients by default and Unix system picked server JVM by default.  In 64-bit this changes so that the server version is always picked.

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.maxMemory()`:

> Returns the **maximum** amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use.

It's an upper bound. It doesn't mean that the JVM pre-allocates this amout of memory. The memory usage of your process will grow as you're creating objects and keeping them around, up to the maximum heap size that you can configure.

> In Windows Task Manager I see that process javaw.exe is eating ~380 Mb RAM

There are many facets to memory usage: there's address space, virtual RAM, physical RAM, etc. Depending on which column you're looking at in Task Manager, the number you're seeing there may have one of many different meanings.

> I swiched to from Windows 7 (32 bit) to Windows 7 (64 bit)

In general, it is true that 64-bit code requires more memory than equivalent 32-bit code. For one thing, pointers are wider and therefore take up more space. This applies to the JVM like it does to any other process. The JVM, however, takes some steps to lessen the impact. One such measure is [CompressedOops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops).

Comment: I don't know witch column I am looking, because I'm from Ukraine and I have russian version of Windows. Literally it's translated as "Memory".